# Only allow ASCII characters in Email Validation with YUP

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'm using React and Yup to validate an email address.

My schema looks like this:

```
const registrationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email().required()
})
```

And my code like this:

```
const handleOnSubmit = async () => {
    const formData = {
      email: props.emailInput
    }
    const isValid = await registrationSchema.isValid(formData)
    setInputErrorState(isValid ? false : true)
  }
```

The code above is doing the validation, but if I input a non-ASCII character like a Japanese or Chinese character it doesn't work. For example: `ハロー@ハロー.com` is passing the validation.

How can I allow only ASCII or romanji characters in my validation with YUP?

Ideal scenario:

- attack.on.titan@gmail.com ✅
- black@clover.com ✅
- ハロー@ハロー.com ❌

Answer (score 1):

Try this out using Regex

```
 const isEmail = email => {
         const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

         if (re.test(String(email).toLowerCase())) {
              return email;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed `yup` and I used the answer suggested by Ibrahim shamma.

Here is the solution (**RFC5322** compliant):

`utils.tsx`

```
// Regex taken from https://emailregex.com/
export const isEmail = email => {
  const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if (re.test(String(email).toLowerCase())) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

`Component/index.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import {isEmail} from '../utils'
export interface ComponentInterface {
 emailInput:string
 setEmailInput: (e: any) => void
}
 
const Component : React.FC<ComponentInterface> = (props:ComponentInterface) => {
 const [inputErrorState, setInputErrorState] = useState(false)
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    if (inputErrorState) {
      setInputErrorState(false)
    }
    props.setEmailInput(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleOnSubmit = () => {
    const isValid = isEmail(props.emailInput)
    setInputErrorState(isValid ? false : true)
  }
  return ( <div> 
           <input
            type='email'
            id='props.emailInput'
            value={emailInput}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
          ></input>
        {inputErrorState && (
          <p>Your error message</p>
        )}
 </div> );
}
 
export default Component;
```